# Swift - Tapjoy Reward Ad

Tags: ios, swift, tapjoy

I'm trying to add a "Message to Earn" that leads to a "Reward ad" into my app, the framework and the ad works fine but there is no reward for watching the ad.

I have tried using the didRequestReward and requestDidSucceed methods but the requestDidSucceed method triggers when an ad is requested and the didRequestReward is never triggered.

I can't find much documentation and whatever is there has to be translated to swift so I'm not sure if what I've done is the problem or I am missing a function or something but here is my version of didRequestReward:

```
func placement(_ placement: TJPlacement!, didRequestReward request: TJActionRequest!, itemId: String!, quantity: Int32) {
    print("WORKING")
    request.completed()
}
```

Any help would be awesome as I have no idea at this point what it could be I'm just gonna keep trying different things to try get it working.